# Socket.io & Node.js & use_strict

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Я использую последние версии node.js и socket.io. При этом приложение стартует в строгом режиме, т.к. повсюду в нем используется синтаксис class expressions.

При коннекте сокета, приложение падает с ошибкой:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property request of #<Socket> which has only a getter
```

Я вычитал на гитхабе что если закомментить строку `(node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:63:16)` то все будет ок, и что это никаим образом не повлияет на работу приложения.

Собственно хочу у вас поинтересоваться, для чего нужна строка `this.request = client.request;`  и где/в какой момент это используется. И действительно ли если ее закомментировать то это не повлияет на работу приложения?

```html
function Socket(nsp, client){
 //..more properties

  this.request = client.request;  

 //..more properties
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> для чего нужна строка `this.request = client.request;`

Эта строка не нужна, ведь ничего не делает.

> И действительно ли если ее закомментировать то это не повлияет на работу приложения?

Да, это так. Вне строгого режима, попытка изменить неизменяемое свойство игноруется по умолчанию.

```
var socket = {
  get request() { return 0; }
};
socket.request = 1;
console.log(socket.request); // 0
```

В строгом режиме, это приводит к ошибке:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property request of `#<Object>` which has only a getter(…)

Comment: А если "Эта строка не нужна, ведь ничего не делает.", зачем ее вообще засунули в модуль? И для чего сам метод необходим function Socket(nsp, client) ?

Comment: @sanu0074 Такой вопрос лучше задать автору модуля. Я не могу сказать что он хотел, когда написал этот код.